# Trying to compare a randomly generated array to user filled array

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a project to create a game of Mastermind. The user must input 3 colors and the program will compare which are the correct color and in the proper place,which are the correct color but in the wrong place, and which are the wrong color.  All seems well except I'm unable to properly compare the info within the randomly generated array with the user filled array. I'm sure I'd have to use a loop to accomplish this.
-Things that I feel may be the issue:
*The information within both arrays are not being stored properly.
*conflicting types.

```
void gameS() {

int close, right, attempts = 0;
string choice[3],code; // holds user input
const int arrySize = 5;

srand(time(0)); //random numbers

string ranColor[arrySize] = { "R", "B", "W", "Y", "G" }; // possible color options

for (int i = 0; i < arrySize - 2; i++)  //generat random colors
{
    int rcolor = rand() % arrySize;
    code = ranColor[rcolor];
    cout << code << endl;
}


while (attempts < 10) {
    cout << "You should input your color choices below. Your options are - R : Red, B : Blue, W : White, Y : Yellow, G : Green.\n" << "Please choose 3 for your " << attempts+1 << " attempt.\n" << "******************************************************\n\n";

    cout << "\n\nPlease enter the color of the first peg: "; //user input to choice array spot : 1
    cin >> choice[0];
    cout << "\nPlease enter the color of the second peg: "; //user input to choice array spot : 2
    cin >> choice[1];
    cout << "\nPlease enter the color of the third peg: "; //user input to choice array spot : 3
    cin >> choice[2];

    attempts++; // proceeds to next turn/attempt

    //checks for correct colors in correct places
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (code == choice[i]) 
        {
            right++;

            choice[i] = "X";

        }
    }
    //Determin the number of right colors in the wrong place
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            if (code[i] == choice[y]) {
                close++;

                choice[i] = "Y";

            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

I receive  errors for the following lines:

*'argument':conversion from tim_t to unsigned in' possible loss of data

`srand(time(0));`

*Using uninitialized memory 'right'

```
`if (code == choice[i]) 
        {
            right++;

            choice[i] = "X";

}`
```

*Using uninitialized memory 'close'

```
`for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            if (code == choice[y])
            {
                close++;

                choice[i] = "Y";

            }
        }
    }
```

*no operator "==" matches these operands.
*Binary '==':o global operator found which takes type 'std::string'(or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
`for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            if (code[i] == choice[y])
            {
                close++;

                choice[i] = "Y";

}`
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "unable to properly compare ..."? Do you get a compiler error, or wrong output?

Comment: `code` is not an array... your code should not compile

Comment: @cigien I receive compiler errors. What I mean is, the elements within the arrays should be compared with each other. If they are the same then the program should move to the next element and check. I feel I might have intended to do this with my code but over looked some detail which is causing these errors.

Comment: Then indicate which lines give the error, and paste the exact error message as well.

Comment: Schedule a sit-down with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). On the agenda should be, "Should `choice` be an array of `string` or will a single `string` containing three characters be enough?"

Comment: @Jarod42 oh, `code` was intended to store the random array. Is assigning the array to the variable `code`  changing it from an array or did I not properly set one up?

Comment: @cigien I have edited the main post to show errors.

Comment: @user4581301 I'll def. give this a shot. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see there is some initialization problems.

First

```
int close, right, attempts = 0;
```

Will leave *close* and *right* empty, simply initialize them properly

```
int close = 0, right = 0, attempts = 0;
```

It looks like you want to use *code* as an array, but the problem is, it is not initialized as an array

```
string choice[3],code; // holds user input
```

A quick fix is

```
string choice[3],code[3]; // holds user input
```

Now, where you generate the answer, there is another syntax problem

```
code = ranColor[rcolor];
```

since you want to store the answer in the *code* array, an index must be specified, in this case

```
code[i] = ranColor[rcolor];
```

The final problem lies in

```
//checks for correct colors in correct places
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (code == choice[i]) 
    {
        right++;

        choice[i] = "X";

    }
}
```

Since *code* is an array now, simply change the condition statement to

```
if (code[i] == choice[i])
```